# What does the raven symbolize (besides death)?

Tags: poetry, symbolism, edgar-allan-poe, the-raven

Whenever I ask a friend about the symbolism of the Raven from *The Raven*, they always seem to say death.

**Is that the only thing the Raven is meant to symbolize?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe the Raven symbolizes death at all, but rather life, in grief of having to live after a loved one is dead. As Poe himself put it in his essay [Philosophy of Composition](http://www.eapoe.org/works/essays/philcomp.htm):

> The reader begins now to regard the Raven as emblematical — but it is
>   not until the very last line of the very last stanza, that the
>   intention of making him emblematical of Mournful and Never-ending
>   Remembrance is permitted distinctly to be seen

The phrase "mournful and never-ending remembrance" is the title of a [biography of Poe](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060923318). It's a theme Poe returned to several times, such as in [Annabel Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annabel_Lee).

Of course authorial intent is only one factor to consider in interpreting a work; see [this discussion](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/the-author-of-a-literary-work-disagrees-with-critics-about-meaning-whos-right). It does, however, jibe with my own understanding of the poem even before I read Poe's explicit thoughts on it.

The Raven is thus even sadder than death itself. The speaker craves forgetfulness, and will *never* have it: his heart shall be "lifted -- Nevermore". He could be content, or at least cope, with loneliness. But the Raven is a constant reminder: he lives not just with the loss but the knowledge of the loss.

Comment: Are you aware that [*The Philosophy of Composition* is sometimes considered to be unreliable](http://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/354/did-lenore-merely-leave-or-is-she-dead#comment563_355), more of a post-facto rationalisation than an accurate description of the author's thought processes in writing? I think this answer should at least acknowledge that, if you're going to use it as a source.

Comment: Sure; I referenced the ongoing discussion of authorial intent elsewhere on the site. I hadn't intended Poe's statement to be definitive, not just with respect to this essay but for any discussion, but I can see how it could have been read that way. Does this acknowledgment suffice?

Answer (score -2):

Obviously the Raven does represent death.  Since we know this, I will not touch on it here.  However, there are a few possibilities other than that:

The raven in popular culture (described [here](http://www.perspectivesmagazine.sk/news/ravens-and-crows-in-mythology-folklore-and-religion/)) can symbolize many things.  Ravens have a wide variety of roles in myths and culture; they can symbolize things from death and war to wisdom to creation of the world.

According many analyses I found while searching (including [this one](http://www.poedecoder.com/essays/raven/) and [this one](http://literatureguides.weebly.com/poe-poetry-analysis-symbolism-in-the-raven.html)), the raven also symbolizes the narrator's inability to do anything about his eventual fate; since the Raven is perpetually saying the same thing ("nevermore"), the narrator knows what the answer will be.  So since the raven usually doesn't speak [citation needed], this is why he chose such a nonsensical animal.

In addition, the raven's perching atop the bust of Pallas might symbolize it's vanquishing of wisdom and justice.

The raven can also symbolize the devil; since the narrator thinks it is from "the Night's Plutonian Shore" and because it is described as a "demon."